# Execute entire DAG using Airflow UI

Tags: python, airflow

I am newbie to airflow, We have a DAG with 3 tasks. Currently we are using Celery Executor as we need the flexibility to run an individual task. We don't want to schedule the workflow, for now it will be manual trigger. Is there any way to execute the entire workflow using the Airflow UI (Same as we have in oozie)?

Executing one task at a time is a pain.

Comment: To clarify, do you want all three of the tasks to run when you run the first task? 
Also please post your relevant code.

Comment: If you set the dependencies and then run the dag from the command line with `airflow trigger_dag id` what is the issue?

Comment: Yes you got that right. We need to run all the task when we run the first.

Sry due to restrictions it won't be possible to post the code. We are going to hand over the DAG to support team where their job would be to manually trigger the workflow. As they don't have much experience with command line we need to execute it via UI.

Comment: Run `airflow schedule` in a separate thread (next to web server). Then you'll be able to manually trigger DAG

Answer (score 7):

In Airflow 1.8 and higher there is a button for each dag on the dashboard that looks like a play button:

[image: play button]

In older versions of Airflow, you can use the dialog found at:

`Browse -> Dag Runs -> Create`

Either one should kick off a dag from the UI.

Comment: Does this allow you to pass arguments to the dag?

Comment: Doesn't this let you add a single run only, and not a range?

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab at it and hopefully you can adapt your code to work with this.

```
default_args = {
'owner': 'airflow',
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': datetime(2015, 6, 1),
'email': ['airflow@airflow.com'],
'email_on_failure': False,
'email_on_retry': False,
'retries': 1,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
# 'queue': 'bash_queue',
# 'pool': 'backfill',
# 'priority_weight': 10,
# 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
}

dag = DAG('your_dag', default_args=default_args)

#start of your tasks

first_task = BashOperator(task_id='print_date',
                          bash_command='python script1_name args',
                          dag=dag)
second_task = BashOperator(task_id='print_date',
                          bash_command='python script2_name args',
                          dag=dag)
third_task = BashOperator(task_id='print_date',
                          bash_command='python script_name args',
                          dag=dag)

#then set the dependencies
second_task.set_upstream(first_task)
third_task.set_upstream(second_task)
```

Then when you trigger the DAG, all three tasks will run in order. If these tasks are *not* dependent on each other, you can remove the `set_upstream()` lines from the script. Note that all of these tasks must be in the same script to run with one command.

Comment: I appreciate your time and effort for the answer. but again as mentioned earlier i want to run it via Airflow dashboard. I don't want to trigger this workflow via command prompt or using scheduling mechanism. Is there any mechanism like a button on clicking it it will run the dag in the order mentioned.?

Comment: Also, you'll probably want to import a few things: 

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```